# Escaping backslash in shell script is requiring 3 backslashes

Tags: shell, sh

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.
In the terminal when I enter:

```sh
$ echo 7\\5
7\5
$ echo 7\5
75
$ echo "7\5"
7\5
$ echo "7\\5"
7\5
```

These are the outputs that i get and are kind of expected too. Cause we need two backslashes to escape a backslash.But the problem that am facing is that when I create a shell script as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "7\\5"
echo "7\5"
echo 7\5
echo 7\\5
```

I get the output as:

```sh
7    # 1
7    # 2
75   # 3
7    # 4
```

which is kind of an unexpected output for `1`,`2` and `4`.I should get an escaped backslash there which I don't see in the output.
After which i tired this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo 7\\\5
echo "7\\\5"
echo "7\\\\\\\5"
```

which results in:

```sh
7
7\5
7\\5
```

Can somebody please explain what's going on.Why am I getting this behaviour..?And how can I fix it..?

Comment: `I get the output` Please walk through the process. How are you creating the script? What terminal are you using to view the result? How are you running your script? In what environment are you working with? What editor are you using? Does `cat -v your_script_file` or `hexdump -C` report any unprintable characters? It looks that the output of your noninteractive command is parsed and `\\` is interpreted as a comment. If you execute `bash ./your_script` do you get the same output?

Comment: @KamilCuk I am using `vim` to create the shell script and the shell that i use is `bash` also as recommended by you I ran `bash ./file.sh` and I got the desired output.But why is it so?

Comment: What is your terminal emulator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators ? What shell are you using? Do you type `./file.sh` to run your program? Would `/bin/sh ./file.sh` result in the same issue? What would `stat /bin/sh` output?

Comment: @KamilCuk `stat /bin/sh` tells me that my shell type is `dash` i.e. `File: /bin/sh -> dash`.Yes,I use `./file.sh` to run my program as i save it with an extension.And finally,`/bin/sh .file.sh` gives the same output as `./file.sh` which is equally bothersome. Also, neither of `hexdump -C file.sh` or `cat -v file.sh` report any unprintable characters.